# Can't refer to Text propery of textbox from TextChanged eventhandler

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem with getting the Text value of a textbox in the TextChanged event handler.

I have the following code. (simplified)

```
public float varfloat;

private void CreateForm()
{
    TextBox textbox1 = new TextBox();
        textbox1.Location = new Point(67, 17);
        textbox1.Text = "12.75";
        textbox1.TextChanged +=new EventHandler(textbox1_TextChanged);
}

private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         varfloat = float.Parse(textbox1.Text);
    }
```

I get the following error:'the name textbox1 does not exist in the current context'.

I probably made a stupid mistake somewhere, but I'm new to C# and would appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared `textBox1` as a *local variable* within `CreateForm`. The variable only exists within that method.

Three simple options:

- Use a lambda expression to create the event handler *within `CreateForm`*:

  ```
  private void CreateForm()
  {
      TextBox textbox1 = new TextBox();
      textbox1.Location = new Point(67, 17);
      textbox1.Text = "12.75";
      textbox1.TextChanged += 
          (sender, args) => varfloat = float.Parse(textbox1.Text);
  }
  ```
- Cast `sender` to `Control` and use that instead:

  ```
  private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Control senderControl = (Control) sender;
      varfloat = float.Parse(senderControl.Text);
  }
  ```
- Change `textbox1` to be an instance variable instead. This would make a lot of sense if you wanted to use it anywhere else in your code.

Oh, and please don't use public fields :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead :

```
private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     varfloat = float.Parse((sender as TextBox).Text);
}
```

Comment: You know that the `sender` parameter is going to be a textbox, so you should just say `(TextBox)sender`.

Comment: @siride, Both are same I don't think so it behaves differently

Comment: they aren't actually the same, in that one performs a type check then a cast, whereas mine just performs a type cast. If it ends up being the case that sender is not a TextBox, your method will throw a null reference exception and mine will throw the proper type cast exception. Finally, my method properly documents the intent and expectations.

Comment: @siride, thanks for the explanation. But if talked about the current scenario this event is only triggered in case of textbox. So it will work quite correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Define the `textbox1` out side CreateForm() at class level scope instead of function scope, so that it is available to `textbox1_TextChanged` event.

```
TextBox textbox1 = new TextBox();

private void CreateForm()
{    
        textbox1.Location = new Point(67, 17);
        textbox1.Text = "12.75";
        textbox1.TextChanged +=new EventHandler(textbox1_TextChanged);
}

private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     varfloat = float.Parse(textbox1.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not added the textbox control to the form.

It can be done as

```
TextBox txt = new TextBox();
txt.ID = "textBox1";
txt.Text = "helloo";
form1.Controls.Add(txt);
```

Comment: For more info 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665472/using-dynamically-created-controls-in-c-sharp

Comment: It's certainly a problem in the original code, but it's not the problem the OP is asking about.

Comment: if the control is created dynamically, it must be added to form else it will not be accessible.

Rectify me if i am wrong.

Comment: I left it out because it wasn't part of the problem, but thank you!

Comment: @Pushpendra you aren't wrong, but, again, the question was not about whether the control was showing up.